when I was trying to import yolo from ultralytics
I have already installed ultralytics but its is not working and shows oserror. what is wrong with my system, I want to know, and how can I fix it
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 4
      2 import pandas as pd
      3 import numpy as np
----> 4 from ultralytics import YOLO

File c:\Users\tate5.DESKTOP-BQ3MNS0\Desktop\footfall\myenv\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\__init__.py:10
      7 # Set ENV Variables (place before imports)
      8 os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = "1"  # reduce CPU utilization during training
---> 10 from ultralytics.data.explorer.explorer import Explorer
     11 from ultralytics.models import NAS, RTDETR, SAM, YOLO, FastSAM, YOLOWorld
     12 from ultralytics.utils import ASSETS, SETTINGS

File c:\Users\tate5.DESKTOP-BQ3MNS0\Desktop\footfall\myenv\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\data\__init__.py:3
      1 # Ultralytics YOLO , AGPL-3.0 license
----> 3 from .base import BaseDataset
      4 from .build import build_dataloader, build_grounding, build_yolo_dataset, load_inference_source
      5 from .dataset import (
      6     ClassificationDataset,
      7     GroundingDataset,
   (...)
     11     YOLOMultiModalDataset,
     12 )
...
--> 148                 raise err
    150     kernel32.SetErrorMode(prev_error_mode)
    153 def _preload_cuda_deps(lib_folder, lib_name):

OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading


To better assist you with this issue, could you please provide more information about your environment setup? Specifically, it would be helpful if you could share:

Your requirements.txt file or Pipfile or equivalent poetry / conda config if you're using one
The Python version you're using
The exact command you're using to run your script

This additional context will help a lot.

FOR WINDOWS

Python should be version>=3.7

Make sure that 'ultralytics' is installed within the same environment from which you are running the code.

Install Pre-requisites:

for pip:
pip install numpy matplotlib opencv-python torch torchvision torchaudio

for conda:
conda install numpy matplotlib opencv-python pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.6 -c pytorch

Note: Replace cudatoolkit=11.6 with the appropriate CUDA toolkit version if you have a different one installed.

Install Ultralytics

for pip:
# Install the ultralytics package from PyPI
pip install ultralytics

for conda:
# Install the ultralytics package using conda(without GPU support i.e. CPU only)
conda install -c conda-forge ultralytics

# Install all packages together using conda(with GPU support)
conda install -c pytorch -c nvidia -c conda-forge pytorch torchvision pytorch-cuda=11.8 ultralytics

put in your GPU's cuda version in cuda={your_gpu_cuda_ver}
Visit here for further details

Are you aware of our policy forbidding AI-generated content? I have edited your answer to remove the first section that appears to be AI-generated. If you believe that this was done unfairly, you can roll back my edit. But only do so if you truly didn't use an AI tool to write it. You don't want to get caught using such tools.

@Chris it’s not that you don’t to get caught using si, even if you don’t get caught it’s still wrong

@Starship, I'm trying to give Ray the benefit of the doubt. But you're right: nobody should be using such tools to answer questions here. At the end of the day it's up to them. I was hinting that the consequences can be severe for people who break the rules. In this instance, I chose to edit out the (almost certainly) AI-generated part of the answer instead of flagging the whole answer for moderator attention.
